# Comparing a file containing a chromosomal region and another containing point coordinates

Tags: python, csv, comparison, bioinformatics

Could I please be advised on the following problem. I have csv files which I would like to compare. The first contains coordinates of specific points in the genome (e.g. chr3: 987654 – 987654). The other csv files contain coordinates of genomic regions (e.g.chr3: 135596 – 123456789). I would like to cross compare my first file with my other files to see if any point locations in the first file overlaps with any regional coordinates in the other files and to write this set of overlap into a separate file. To make things simple for a start, I have drafted a simple code to cross compare between 2 csv files. Strangely, my code runs and prints the coordinates but does not write the point coordinates into a separate file. My first question is if my approach (from my code) at comparing these two files optimal or is there a better way of doing this? Secondly, why is it not writing into a separate file?

```
import csv

Region = open ('Region_test1.csv', 'rt', newline = '')
reader_Region = csv.reader (Region, delimiter = ',')

DMC = open ('DMC_test.csv', 'rt', newline = '')
reader_DMC = csv.reader (DMC, delimiter = ',')

DMC_testpoint = open ('DMC_testpoint.csv', 'wt', newline ='')
writer_Exon = csv.writer (DMC_testpoint, delimiter = ',')



for col in reader_Region:
    Chr_region = col[0]
    Start_region = int(col[1])
    End_region = int(col [2])
    for col in reader_DMC:
        Chr_point = col[0]
        Start_point = int(col [1])
        End_point = int(col[2])
        if Chr_region == Chr_point and Start_region <= Start_point and End_region >= End_point:
            print (True, col)
        else:
            print (False, col)
            writer_Exon.writerow(col)


Region.close()
DMC.close()
```

Comment: what is `readers` i don't see a definition.

Comment: Its been a while since I've done genomics, but I am wondering if you can achieve your comparison with BLAST

Comment: Sorry, the line containing readers was an unnecessary statement. I have removed that.

Comment: I don't think blast would be appropriate for this case as I don't think BLAST would allow upload of files for comparison.

Comment: can you give us a sample line of each file and the output?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are wrong, not the least of which is that you never check to see if your files opened successfully.  The most glaring is that you never close your writer.

That said this an incredibly non-optimal way to go about the program. File I/O is slow. You don't want to keep rereading everything in a factorial fashion.  Given how your search requires all possible comparisons you'll want to store at least one of the two files completely in memory, and potentially use a generator/iterator over the other if you dont wish to store both complete sets of data in memory.

One you have both sets loaded, proceed to do your intersection checks

I'd suggest you take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html for how to use a csv reader because what you are doing doesn't appear to make anysense because col[0], col[1] and col[2] aren't going to be what you think they are.

These are style and readability things but:
The names of some iteration variables seem a bit off, `for col in ...` should probably be `for token in ...`  because you are processing token by token, and not column by columns/line by line, etc.

Additionally it would be nice to pick something consistent to stick to for your variables, sometimes you start with uppercase, sometimes you save the uppercase for after your '_'

That are putting ' ' between your objects and some function noames and not others is also very odd.   But again these dont change the functionality of your code.